# How to resolve bad symbolic reference and No implicit view available from String errors in Play Framework?

Tags: postgresql, scala, anorm

I am running Play application(2.2.3), I am getting the following errors, I am not sure why I am getting these ? How to resolve these?

Errors:

```
1. bad symbolic reference, A signature in JavaTimeColumn.class refers to term time
[error] in package java which is not available
[error] it may be cokpletely missing from the current classpath, or the version
[error] the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling JavaTimeColumn.class
[error]  get[Pk[Long]]<"id"> ~
[error]               ^   

2. No implicit view available from String => anorm.ParameterValue.
[error] 'content -> jsondata.content
[error]          ^
[error] two errors found
```

build.scala:

```
val dependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.typesafe.play" %% "anorm" % "2.4.0",
    "org.webjars" % "requirejs" % "2.1.1",
    "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1200-jdbc41",
    "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901.jdbc4",
    )
```

Comment: I would be much more better to paste the error as text, rather than screenshot

Comment: As your code seems to be for old Anorm (2.2), it was indicated in the [migration guide 2.3](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration23#Anorm) there changes about parameters, to be more typesafe.

Comment: I have added the error in the description

Comment: @cchantep, thanks for your reply, means How can I add/resolve those parameters for my requirement(in jsoncontent.scala)  for Anorm 2.4.0 ?

Comment: I have resolved it now by adding the statement: "com.typesafe.play" %% "anorm" % "2.3.9", instead of "com.typesafe.play" %% "anorm" % "2.4.0". Hopefully it may be helpful to anyone !! Thanks !

Comment: That means your code is still using deprecated thingy, another update will be needed for 2.4.

Comment: If I use 2.4.0, it's giving errors like bad symbolic reference, A signature in JavaTimeColumn.class refers to term time and No implicit view available from String => anorm.ParameterValue. And I have cleaned Play and ran the application, working good.

Comment: Means you have a dependency conflict, same class in different JAR, not used in the appropriate version.